# How to retrieve back/keep the last data/value in Edittext when the app is reopen

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-sharedpreferences

In my case, I would like to retrieve back the last data I type into Edittext, whatever I reopen the app or intent back to the activity.

Is there have any solution to fix that problem? I was thinking about using SharedPreferences to auto retrieve back while intent to the activity.

Comment: Yes you can use `SharedPreferences`. Try with it.

Comment: SharedPreferences is best solution for this. otherwise you can use sqlite Database also.

Comment: go ahead use sharedPrefrences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [shared preferences](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) in [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) or in button click

Save values

```
   SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("YourPreferenceName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  

Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("textvalue", "value");
editor.commit();
```

Get Values

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("YourPreferenceName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String textvalue = sharedpreferences.getString("textvalue", "default_value");
```